# why is &nbsp; not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want space added between firstname and lastname where   are added. but when i run the code it doesnt adds space. I also tried adding tab sapce as well but its not rendering correctly. The character set is set to utf-8 as can be seen in the attached html

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  title: string;
  clicked: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstName = `John`;
    this.lastName = `Doe`;
  }

  printDetails(frstnm: HTMLInputElement, lstnm: HTMLInputElement, event: any): void {
    this.firstName = frstnm.value || this.firstName;
    this.lastName = lstnm.value || this.lastName;
    this.title = `First Name is: ${this.firstName}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Last Name is: ${this.lastName}`;
    event.preventDefault();
    this.clicked = true;
  }
  isVisible() {
    const classes = {
        display : this.clicked
    }
    return classes;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Angular escapes html entities. Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding

Comment: Does it work if you do `\u00A0`?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes it did work. why?

Comment: @SONGSTER because \u00A0 is not an HTML Entity

Comment: what is it? can you please give more details about it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using HTML in your title does not make sense. If you wanted to use `&nbsp;` then you'd have to render the title as HTML for it to render properly, but that also means if a user had any HTML in their *name*, it would be an issue. If I register for your site with `FirstName: "a <b>name</b>"` then it would render as bold alongside the spaces.

Instead you should leave it as normal text, and put an actual non-breaking space character in your code, using [JS unicode escapes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode), instead of HTML escapes, e.g. use [`\u00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)

```
this.title = `First Name is: ${this.firstName}\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Last Name is: ${this.lastName}`;
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming this is Angular.

the spaces are not printing because `&nbsp;` should be rendered as HTML.

```
<div [innerHTML]="title"></div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0SGQq2aPtJCAbLp7t6bq?p=preview)

Answer (score -2):

What if you simply add the space like this?

```
this.title = `First Name is: ${this.firstName} Last Name is: ${this.lastName}`;
```

(Notice the space between `...firstName}` and `Last...`)

Comment: Okay, I assumed you were passing the text through to the `innerHTML` property in the template (like @Michael mentioned).