# Adding whitespace to a string in typescript (in angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method in one of my components that gets called in my html page whenever I click on a button. I am currently trying to format the page so that certain attributes (namely city and state) appear at fixed locations in
the page. This is what I have so far:

```
if (this.city !== undefined) {
   let test = 50;
   test -= this.city.length;
   let result = 'City: ' + this.city;
   for ( let i = 0; i < test; i++) {
       result += ' ';
   }
   return result + this.state;
}
```

However, instead of seeing something like City:

```
                                       (41 extra spaces) Grapevine TX
```

it looks like City:

```
Grapevine TX.
```

The interesting thing is that extra characters are added as long as they aren't spaces. For example, if I wrote result += 'a', then I would see 41 extra a's in the string.

Using the result += 'a' example, if I wrote the line result = result.replace(/a/g, ' '), then the final output would be City: Grapevine TX. However, if I had originally written result += ' ' and then wrote result = result.replace(/ /g, 'a'), then even though the extra spaces would not appear in the original string, those spaces would be replaced by an 'a.'

**How do I add extra whitespace to my string?**

Comment: Try adding &nbsp; instead of a space

Comment: HTML omits multiple whitespaces. Unless you use non-breakable ones. However, I suspect you are better off fixing this using CSS and/or other formatting.

Comment: You can add space as a html character entity like this: &nbsp;

Comment: `&nbsp;` might not be encoded into an acutal non-breaking space (for certain string-encoding-safety aspects of angular), [unicode escape codes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46223835/444255) will work better.

Answer (score 3):

Try use next code in your css:

```
.pre-class {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

[image]

**But be careful** — text will be shown as is with all empty spaces and new rows!

Answer (score 3):

You can add white spacess by adding `\xa0`.

eg:

```
result = result.concat("\xa0");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is related to html which omits multiple spaces following another space. Angular is not the root cause.

Pure html Example -  Both headlines are dispalyed equally :

```html
<h1>test     test<h1> 
<h1>test test<h1>
```

Solution:
use tags and/or css for layouting your output.

Comment: is there no way to put multiple spaces following another space in html other than &nbsp (b/c i'm trying to make the amount variable)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ' ' you can try `&nbsp;`

Comment: The code i'm writing is in a .ts file not in the html file.

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented you in other answers, the problem in your case is with the html.
I recommend you to add `&nbsp;` instead of `' '` in your code.

```
if (this.city !== undefined) {
   let test = 50;
   test -= this.city.length;
   let result = 'City: ' + this.city;
   for (let i = 0; i < test; i++) {
       result += '&nbsp;';
   }
   return result + this.state;
}
```

Or if you prefer, you can embed your string result into `<pre></pre>` tags.

You can check out this page https://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Spaces-in-HTML for further information.

Comment: The code i'm writing is in a .ts file not in the html file. Also, I tried editing my code according to what you said earlier and it didn't work. Did you word your answer assuming that I was writing my code in the html file?

Comment: Have you tried binding your variable with innerHtml tag? Like <p [innerHtml]="YOUR_VARIABLE"></p>

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get extra spaces in string, html will not render the extra spaces. You can get the count of whitespaces needed and loop in html wherever wanted. Tested and it works.

```
<span *ngFor="let i of whitespacecount">&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use   to create a space in typescript
For example:

`<h1>Hello World<h1>`

can be written as

`<h1>Hello &nbsp; World<h1>`

This will display it as a space on the page view.